# After the weblogic deserialization patch is installed, the axis2 return message is missing the namespace

Tags: java, apache-axis, weblogic-10.x

My weblogic version is 10.3.6.0, weblogic's deserialization patch was recently installed, and the axis2 application that was deployed on weblogic returned a message that lacked a namespace.
Before installed，response like this：

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

After response is：

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>....</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And when start up project,i recrive weblogic warn:

```
[WARN] Unable to determine dialect of the STAX implement at jar:file:/web/weblogic/patch_wls1036/patch_jars/BUG26519424_10360171017.jar!
```

If delete this jar ,everything is normal!
I think it may be my axis2 / wsdl2Java setting problems

please kindly help. Thank alot.